# CSS3 - Rotation by fixed side

Tags: html, css

See a fiddle to demonstrate my issue:

```
div:hover{
    -webkit-transform:  rotateX(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
div {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lbq3K/

I would like to flip a div with the bottom line completely fixed throughout the movement. I've been googling around a lot, but couldn't find a solution. As you can see in the fiddle, when you hover your mouse over the div, the bottom line of the border moves away from the `<hr>` line at the bottom, and gets rotated back afterwards. I would like to have the rotation with a completely fixed bottom border, like I'd flip a calendar page. I've tried transform-origin to fix the rotation, but it apparently isn't working. Is there a way to do this just CSS?

Comment: You could do a `bottom:#px;` or `margin-bottom:-#px` transition alongside the transition you already have to possibly get your desired effect. I don't think there's a sure-fire way in the transform stuff to do what you want tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you put your transform origin on your `DIV` properties instead of in your `DIV:hover` it works.

In code:

use this:

```
div:hover{
    -webkit-transform:  rotateX(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
div {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;

}
```

instead of this:

```
div:hover{
    -webkit-transform:  rotateX(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
div {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Wow, awesome! Thank you. Could you help me understand the logic behind it? Superb.

Comment: well, basically the default transform-origin value is :50% 50%;/*right on the center of the object*/and when you set a different value on a pseudo-class it doesn't change the value on the original object/*but yes the other way around*/ so when you hover over the object, it makes a transition between transform-origin:50% 50% and transform-origin:center/*50%*/ bottom/*100%*/

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard about [perspective-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/perspective-origin)?
I'm not sure about it, but I think

```
div {
    ...
    perspective-origin:100% 100%;
}
```

should work fine for you. My testing was successful.
perspective-origin defines the point from which the viewer is looking at the element.

Comment: Yes, I have and I've tried, it, didn't seem to be what I was looking for. siabaJS's solution worked, though! :)